# Formula to return the next upcoming Thursday

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need an Excel formula that takes a given day and provides the next upcoming Thursday of that week. I have a list of dates with time stamp attached:

```
Date        Week Ending
10/5/2015   10/8/2015
10/11/2015  10/15/2015
10/21/2015  10/22/2015
10/27/2015  10/29/2015
```

I want to convert it to the weekending. The example is of my date and the "Week Ending" I want the formula to show.

Comment: Date
10/5/2015
10/11/2015
10/21/2015
10/27/2015

Comment: Week Ending
10/8/2015
10/15/2015
10/22/2015
10/29/2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Date` is in A1, if @Grade 'Eh' Bacon's solution is not working for you and given your mention of *time stamp attached*, maybe treat your dates as text and say, in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=LEFT(A2,10)+(7-WEEKDAY(LEFT(A2,10),15))
```

Comment: I like this as a catchall; dealing with Excel dates can be very frustrating in how different the display vs core value can be.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in A1, the formula is simply:

```
=A1+(7-WEEKDAY(A1,15))
```

Weekday(A1,15) gives the number of the day of the week of a given date, and the option ,15 says use a week starting with Fri and ending with Thurs. So, a given date, + (7-Weekday()) will give you the number of days required to get to the 'week ending with the Thursday on x date'.

Comment: It is not giving me the result as shown on the "weekending"

Comment: Works for me. Make sure to replace A1 with the cell reference that has your date.

Comment: I have tested and confirmed that this gives exactly the results you expected in your original data block in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Thursday to return the same date, then try:

```
=A1+7-WEEKDAY(A1+2)
```

The more generalized version would be:

```
=A1+7-WEEKDAY(A1+7-DOW)
```

where DOW (DayOfWeek) translates

- Sun = 1
- Mon = 2
- ...
- Sat = 7